# When was the first time an author directed the adaptation of their own book?

Tags: first-appearance, book-adaptation

Stephen Chbosky wrote *The Perks of Being a Wallflower* and also directed the movie adaptation.

Has this been done before?

Comment: Definitely. Elia Kazan is the earliest example [in this list](http://www.film.com/movies/authors-directors-perks-of-being-a-wallflower) (*America America* in 1963), but I'm not sure it's the first.

Comment: [The Homesteader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Homesteader) released in March 1919 is another example but there could be others before this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[The Homesteader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Homesteader)* was a book by Oscar Micheaux and made into a film in **1919**.

Elia Kazan turned his autobiographical book, *[America America](http://www.film.com/movies/authors-directors-perks-of-being-a-wallflower)* (published 1961), into a film (released **1963**).

> In 1964, Elia Kazan was nominated for three Academy Awards for his adaptation of “America, America,” a film which he wrote and directed based upon his own book. Sure, he’d already had a few Oscars on the shelf for “Gentleman’s Agreement” and “On the Waterfront,” but having a few nods for his own original (loosely biographical) story was probably a special honor for Kazan.

Comment: Even though these examples were given earlier, I'm accepting this to help those who stumble across this.

Answer (score 1):

Dalton Trumbo, *Johnny Got His Gun* (novel: 1938, film: 1971). Elia Kazan also directed the movie version (1969) of his novel *The Arrangement* (1967).